# Drupal with imce with S3 SLOW performance issue

Tags: amazon-s3, drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, imce-file-browser

I have configured my drupal site so that all images/files/media etc is handled my s3 by using `S3 file system` module.

Now everything works fine, the image/file/ field uploader works fine but there is a huge performance issue when using IMCE file browser from the WYSIWYG editor. It takes at least a minute for the browser to display its content and there are only 290 images with 78 MB used in that initial folder which should not cause such huge delays. This is having a huge impact for our editors and several minutes lost just to upload a couple of images.

I tried various pagination patch and there is no difference at all in the performance. 
What are my options now

Comment: Ran across this issue in the context of D8 s3fs contrib with IMCE. 7.x and 8.x patches are available at https://www.drupal.org/project/imce/issues/2962030#comment-12853170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As drilled through many forms and discussions, turns out that IMCE was not meant for S3 file system and I found [this](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/DRUP-D7-IMCEchangedfors3-120417-1240-362_0.pdf) patch in pdf form(warning downloads rather than opens )

I followed the steps in that patch which significantly improved my performance.